# Bitbucket pipeline AWS ECR with assume role

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, amazon-ecr

I have the current pipeline definition:

```
- step: &run_test
        name: Testing service
        image: 
          name: <account>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<repository>:latest
          aws:
            access-key: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
            secret-key: $AWS_SECRET_KEY
```

The account needs to assume a role to access the sub-organization where the ecr repository lives.

From my local terminal i can get secret, key and token via

`aws_credentials=$(aws sts assume-role --profile chatbot --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/<role> --role-session-name "RoleSession1" --output json)`

But how can i use the image in the pipeline?